# How to get all nodes with a particular relationship from a given node using neo4j-scala wrapper?

Tags: scala, neo4j

I have a node(A) and relationship (relation).

```
A--> "relation" --> B
```

How do I get all B nodes that are related to the given A node using neo4j-scala wrapper ?

Comment: neo4j scala returns the normal `org.neo4j.graphdb.Node` objects, so it will work like in the linked question

Comment: I want to know if there are any methods in neo4j scala for getting the  above nodes